# Oracle SqlPlus Trigger no funciona

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

estoy trabajando con SqlPlus, aún no domino mucho el tema y estoy empezando con los Triggers, tengo este Trigger, el cual considero no demasiado complicado:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fecha_hora_fecha_fin
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RESIDENCIA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
fechain DATE;
fechafin DATE;
existe VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
SELECT fecha_hora INTO fechain FROM RESIDENCIA where nseq=:NEW.nseq;
SELECT fecha_fin INTO fechafin FROM RESIDENCIA where nseq=:NEW.nseq;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN existe :='NULL';
/*IF existe = 'NULL'
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'ERROR:nseq no existe en residencia');
END IF;*/
IF fechain > fechafin
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'ERROR:La fecha_fin debe ser menor o igual a fecha_hora');
END IF;
END;
/
```

El trigger se crea sin problema pero al hacer esta inserción, la cual debería hacer saltar el trigger este no actúa y se inserta normalmente:

```
INSERT INTO RESIDENCIA
(nseq, fecha_hora, fecha_fin)
VALUES
(123, to_date('2021-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2021-01-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Agradecería si pudieseis decirme por qué esto no funciona.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Estás intentando validar las fechas en el registro que insertas, pero estás haciendo un select sobre la tabla RESIDENCIA siendo que es un trigger BEFORE INSERT. Así pues, tus búsquedas no traerán resultados, existe es null y ninguna excepción es lanzada. Por qué no comparas directamente las dos fechas de `:new`?

Comment: Justo, tienes razón, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas, buscas validar que las fechas en el INSERT o en el UPDATE sean válidas. Que el inicio esté antes que el fin.

Pero estás validando en la tabla y es BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE. Demás que no tiene mucho sentido mirar la tabla si lo que quieres es validar los datos nuevos que van a quedar en el registro. Sería algo así.

Ya lo que no está muy claro es por qué necesitas saber si el registro ya existe o no, pero no lo dices en la pregunta.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fecha_hora_fecha_fin
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON RESIDENCIA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    existe VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.fecha_hora > :NEW.fecha_fin
        THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'ERROR:La fecha_fin debe ser menor o igual a fecha_hora');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Efectivamente, con eso me vale, error de novato supongo, muchas gracias :)